# Determining the type of terminal (classic Unix terminal vs graphical terminal)

Tags: bash

I'm configuring my prompt (`PS1`) via **.bashrc** and found one issue with my current configuration: I am using a 256 color scheme. This is not compatible with the classical terminal (accessible via e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) but looks beautiful in graphical terminals such as gnome-terminal, terminator, etc.

So I have to change my prompt depending on the type of terminal. To do this, I need a condition for `if` clause to test the type of terminal. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: FYI, "classic terminal" is known as the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `TERM` variable indicates the terminal type.
when running in an x-terminal, it is usually `xterm` (but can also be `xterm-color-256` as Dmitry has hinted in his answer).
the following code checks whether the value of $TERM starts with `xterm` (and thus catches several cases):

```
case "$TERM" in
   xterm*)
      echo "running as an x-terminal"
      ;;
   *)
      echo "not running as an x-terminal"
      ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

`echo $TERM` would give you the terminal type

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if [ "$TERM" == "xterm-color-256" ]; then echo "YES"; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: look at the parent process of the current shell. If its "login", you're in a console

```
parent=$(ps --pid $(ps --pid $$ --no-headers --format ppid) --no-headers --format cmd)
if [[ $parent == login* ]]; then
    echo console
    PS1='plain> '
else
    echo assume you can get away with more
    PS1='fancy> '
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the value of `$TERM` to decide if you have a color terminal or not, but this value could be modified. The question is where this environment variable is being set when a new terminal window is opened.

This would be in the `.bashrc` file. However, a word of warning:

- The value of `$TERM` may be a lie. This is just an environment variable that's set. How it is set is determined by the terminal program (on the Mac, the `Terminal.app` can set the terminal to `xterm`, `xterm-color`, `vt100`, `ansi`, and several others..
- The terminal could be a color terminal, but doesn't use ANSI color codes. You could be in trouble if you simply assume that a particular escape sequence gets you a particular color.
- If your prompt is set in the `.bashrc` file, changing the value of `$TERM` won't change the prompt.

That said, I would probably do something like this:

```
case $TERM in
    *color*)    PS1=...;;
    *)          PS1=...;;
esac
```

This way, my terminal will be set to color if I said it was an `xterm-color` or `xterm-256color`.